# What sort of knowledge are we entitiled to have?

Tags: knowledge, rights

What sort of knowledge are we entitiled to have? Is there a class of knowledge which we should not be deliberately deprived of? I have asked before about anonymity, the right not to tell, deception, conspiracy etc., but I wondered if it could all be humped into one group of things to know. A "libraries gave us power" kinda thing, but primarily about other people and their secrets.

### Anything?

I'm just interested in what sort of knowledge you or I might righfully feel not just legally entitled to, but **morally** entitiled to, and just assume that no-one *ought* lie about anything. Assuming there is such knowledge, I acknowledge that there is a gap in how bad the vice is, dependent on who it is that *doesn't tell*.

I'd have thought this includes such things as, arguably at least, the laws of the nation state where you dwell, the identity of your children, your medical etc. records and status, the whereabouts of your own property etc., when someone you legally care for (or vice versa) dies,  the dangers of your profession, how to vote, and so on (all just pretty random examples).

Comment: see [wikipedia: right to know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_know#United_States)

Comment: You may get better answers if you distinguish between: 1: What moral obligations incur on individuals to transmit knowledge at one's own expense? (Which kinds of knowledge, what kind of recipient, how much expense?) --- 2: What legal obligation should the state have to transmit knowledge at the state's expense? (Same qualifiers.) --- 3: What transmission of knowledge by others are individuals morally prohibited from impeding?

Comment: that's a fair idea of how best to eleborate the question, but i don't feel it necessarily *needs* that, though we'll see, i guess @gs

Comment: fleshed it out with examples instead @gs hope that works for you